# Open a certain file format

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have and App that opens several types of files by using the QuickLook.framework, but i cant open .dwg files (autoCAD),i need to open it from inside my App, is there a way to do it using IOS or by using a another framework?

How do you guys solved this problem?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can always just open the file, then interpret the bits yourself.

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution for it. I am also looking to open .dwg file in iOS.

Comment: Yes, use the QuickLook.framework and download the Autocad app for iphone from the apple store, it works like this: once you have the Autocad app installed when you open the dwg with quicklook framework you click on the top right button of the view and it will show the option to open with Autocad, and thats it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quicklook only supports the most common files.  You could search for a third party framework that will display them, or inquire of Autocad if they have a library which would allow your app to open and display their files. Otherwise, in order to open a file you need to have an app that has registered that it will open that file, then you can launch that using the right URL call.